# Scala - Creating a new list by combining the contents of one list and the hierarchy of another

Tags: list, scala, nested

I am trying to create a new list that combines the contents of one single-level list with the hierarchy of another nested list and link them by the IDs of objects in both lists. Note: the ID for the BChain object is stored within the ItemObj inside it.

I have **three** objects:

```
ItemObj(id: String, stored: DateTime)
BChain(item: ItemObj, List[BChain])
AChain(aid: String, List[AChain])
```

I have two lists:

```
val nestedList: List[AChain]
val singleLevelList: List[BChain]
```

I want the second list to have the hierarchy of the first, but still contain it's own elements. Therefore, `BChain` should include the original `ItemObj` and `List[BChain]` properties (including all of `ItemObj`'s original property data - ID and DateTime) when it is put into the newly desired list output.

So Instead of (input):

```
 val nestedList = List(
 AChain("123", List(AChain("456", [])),
 AChain("789", [])
)

val singleLevelList = List(
 BChain(ItemObj("123", DateTime), []),
 BChain(ItemObj("456", DateTime), []),
 BChain(ItemObj("789", DateTime), []))
)
```

I would like the following output:

```
val combinedLists = List(
     BChain(ItemObj("123", DateTime), List(BChain(ItemObj("456", DateTime), [])),
     BChain(ItemObj("789", DateTime), [])
)
```

as the final list.

Note: There may be more items in the nested list than the single-level list, and if this is the case then the extra items should be ignored. Each of the items in the single-level list should correspond to one of the items in the nested list.

How can I accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have edited my question.

Comment: Task is not clear since combinedList in output is the same as nestedList in input, so it is not obvious what kind of operations supposed to be done for nestedList except changing AChain to BChain wrapper. If there's a case when something should be ignored please provide this example

Comment: It is not the same. The objects are different. For simplicity's sake I have omitted the object properties. These are two entirely different objects that share the same ID value.

`nestedList` is a nested list of `AChain`. `combinedLists` is a nested list of `BChain`, where the `BChain` objects are taken from the `singleLevelList` of `BChain` objects.

Comment: so in output you just want to repeat the hierarchy of  nestedList but with singleLevelList objects?

Comment: The combined list is the hierarchy of the first list with the content of the second list (therefore no `AChain` objects)

Comment: @DmitryReutov Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Lets say we have only 456 element in single level list, should we extract 456 from 123 list and put it to the root level?

Comment: No that's not necessary. Basically, the `singleLevelList` (BChain) can only be created if the items in the `nestedList` (AChain) already exist. So if 123 exists in the `singleLevelList`, then 123 already definitely exists in the `nestedList`.

Comment: i mean the opposite, 123 is missing in single list, but we have 456 in single list

Comment: That scenario is fine, 123 can exist in nestedList and not exist in singleLevelList.

Comment: so then we put 456 on a first level, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I had to dummy up a `DateTime` type and value so that the following would compile.

```
case class ItemObj(id: String, stored: DateTime)
case class BChain(item: ItemObj, bcl :List[BChain])
case class AChain(aid: String, acl :List[AChain])
```

Then I changed your `singleLevelList` into real Scala code and created a `Map` for fast lookup.

```
val singleLevelList = List(
  BChain(ItemObj("123", DateTime), Nil),
  BChain(ItemObj("456", DateTime), Nil),
  BChain(ItemObj("789", DateTime), Nil)
)

val sLLMap = singleLevelList.groupBy(_.item.id)
```

Next a recursive method to change all `AChain`s to `BChain`s.

```
def a2b(aLst :List[AChain]) :List[BChain] =
  aLst.map(a => BChain(sLLMap(a.aid).head.item, a2b(a.acl)))
```

Now to test it.

```
val nestedList = List(
  AChain("123", List(AChain("456", Nil))),
  AChain("789", Nil)
)

a2b(nestedList)  //appears to work
```

Of course this will throw if `nestedList` has an A without a corresponding B in the `singleLevelList`.

Comment: The `stored` property already exists in the ItemObj. How would I carry that across or do some kind of BChain copy and just update the `bcl`?

Comment: I can't make out your question. Carry what across to where? `stored` is part of the `ItemObj` which is copied in its entirety to the new structure. The original `bcl` values in the `singleLevelList` are not copied because the structure of the `nestedList` determines the new `bcl` values.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise that comment had been added, I was confused about the stored property but I misunderstood why you were creating the dummy values. I am trying out your solution now, it seems like it should work fine. I will update you soon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is one problem. When the `sLLMap` is created, it changes the order of the IDs (not using example data, but data fetched from DB - same structure/types), meaningthe two inner BChains in sLL are in a different order from the two inner AChains in nL. This is a problem because it now can't find an ID at a particular point and results in a `key not found` exception. Any ideas to avoid this?

Comment: I've sorted the nestedList at each level by the aid, but I am still experiencing the same problems. I'll update if I find a solution.

Comment: Fixed my issue. This solution has worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you want?

```
final case class ItemObj(id: String, stored: DateTime)
final case class BChain(item: ItemObj, list: List[BChain])
final case class AChain(aid: String, list: List[AChain])

def combine(as: List[AChain], bs: List[BChain]): List[BChain] = {
  val asMap = as.iterator.map(a => a.aid -> a.list).toMap

  def toBChain(a: AChain): BChain =
    BChain(
      item = ItemObj(id = a.aid, stored = ???),
      list = a.list.map(toBChain)
    )

  bs.map {
    case BChain(item, list) =>
      val newElements =
        asMap
          .getOrElse(key = item.id, default = Nil)
          .map(toBChain)

      BChain(
        item,
        list ::: newElements
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please be able to alter your solution to account for something I mistakenly omitted in my question? The BChain object is actually `BChain(ItemObj, List[BChain])`. The ID that I need from BChain is actually on the `ItemObj` in Bchain. So... `final case class ItemObj(id: String, stored:DateTime)`, `final case class BChain( item: ItemObj, listL List[BChain])`. The `AChain()` class is correct, but I forgot out that important detail about the `ItemObj`

Comment: I'll update my question. Apologies, I realise this complicates things more.

Comment: @Chris I updated my answer, now the question is how would you create the `stored` field of all nested **BChains**? With the same value as the one of the root?

Comment: I want the `stored` property that already exists in `ItemObj` to be carried over. It shouldn't need to be created again. I appreciate your help

Comment: @Chris So you mean the nested **BItems** shouldn't preserve the original ids of their **AItems** but rather use the same **ItemObj**? It would be better if you could just be clear with your question, show many inputs and expected outputs and use correct scala syntax.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Apologies for that not being clear. Each ItemObj ID corresponds to an AChain object's ID. The issue I am having is keeping the entire ItemObject. I need to retain all of the original data in the object. I will update my question to provide better detail.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work even if root element of nested list is absent in single level list

```
final case class ItemObj(id: String, stored: DateTime = null)
final case class AChain(aid: String, children: List[AChain] = List())
final case class BChain(bid: ItemObj, children: List[BChain] = List())

val nestedList = List(
  AChain("123", List(AChain("456"))),
  AChain("789")
)

def getCombineList(nestedList: List[AChain], singleList: List[BChain]): List[BChain] = {
  val singleListMap = singleList.groupBy(_.bid.id)

  def combine(items: List[AChain]): List[BChain] = {
    items flatMap {item => 
      val children = combine(item.children)
      val parent = singleListMap.get(item.aid).map(v =>
        List(v.head.copy(children = children))
      ).getOrElse(
        children
      )
      parent
    }
  }

  combine(nestedList)
}

val s = getCombineList(nestedList, List(BChain(ItemObj("456")), BChain(ItemObj("789"))))
```

Comment: I have updated my question with an extra layer of complexity. See the comment above for a brief explanation. Sorry to complicate things. I appreciate your help regardless. If you could update your answer to accommodate the `ItemObj` inside `BChain`, that would be great. But if you don't have time, that's okay, thanks anyway!

Comment: No problems, just slight changes. Check please my update

Comment: @Chris, check if you have case class property names the same as mine...if not then correct the code

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. My property name was wrong. However, I now get a type mismatch at `children = children` saying that it requires an 'ItemObj' but finds a `List[RuleChain]` instead. It may be another property name. I need to name them to be more clear.

Comment: @Chris, please copy my code as it is to check, it works perfectly well and then just edit according your names

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, yes, but i dont write code for production, just an algorythm that OP could get it since questions needs help, not a code ready for production

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, yes, i appreciate your advices almost always